# Hyperbolic distance of a point from center in Klein-Beltrami disk model

Tags: metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry

According to [the Wikipedia entry about Klein Beltrami disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model#Distance_formula), I found that the hyperbolic distance between two points P and Q is determined by the following formula :

$$d(P, Q) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{|AQ||PB|}{|AP||QB|}$$

Where A and B are on the euclidian line $(PQ)$ and on the unit Circle.
$|AQ| > |AP|$ and $|PB| > |QB|$

Now, I want to know the hyperbolic distance between O the center of unit disk and a point P.

$$d(O, Q) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{|AQ||OB|}{|AO||QB|}$$
Now I think $|OB| = |AO| = 1$
$$d(O, Q) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{|AQ|}{|QB|}$$
Since A, Q and B are aligned and A et B belong to the unit circle :

$|AB| = |AQ| + |QB| = 2$

and $|AQ| = |AO| + |OQ|$

and $|QB| = |OB| - |OQ|$

Considering $|OQ| = r$ I conclude :
$$d(O, Q) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+r}{1-r}$$
$$d^{-1}(O, Q) = \frac{e^{2r} - 1}{e^{2r}+1}$$

Am I correct ?

Comment: all correct  (i think i wrote that) see also the formulas for tanh and artanh at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Comment: @Willemien : nice ! I didn't realise these function already had names !

Comment: it is now also added to the wikipedia page  :)

Comment: @Willemien: Don't you want to make your comments an answer? There is little to add to that, I think.

Comment: @Willemien : plus I would validate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All correct (I think I wrote that on wikipedia) 
$$d(O, Q) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+r}{1-r} = \operatorname{artanh} r$$

see also the formulas for tanh and artanh at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

I have added it to the wikipedia page

ps related:

For the Poincare disk model  he hyperbolic distance between O the center of unit disk and a point P an Euclidean distance r away is $d(O, P) = \ln \frac{1+r}{1-r} = 2 \operatorname{artanh} r $.